# Function arguments in execution context and scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In chapter 4 of Professional JavaScript for Web Developers by Nicholas C. Zakas, author says that function arguments follow the same access rules as any other variable in the execution context. For that, I tested the follows code:

```
function n1(num1, num2) {
   function n2() {
      var num3 = (num1 + num2);
      console.log(num3);
   }
}
```

I called n1() function with: *n1(1, 2)*. I thought that the result would be 3, but I get *undefined*.

**Why this behavior?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `n1`, nor `n2` doesn't return anything (that's where `undefined` comes from). Additionally, `n2` is never called. If you want to get `3` from `n1(1, 2)` you have to modify it something like this:

```
function n1(num1, num2) {
   function n2() {
      var num3 = (num1 + num2);
      console.log(num3);
      return num3;
   }
   return n2();
}
```

Comment: Oh! That's right! Too obvious and I couldn't see it! Thanks a lot Pavlo!

Comment: BTW, can you modify the return statement in n2() function? It must be "num3". I tryed but the edit must be 6 characters at least.

Comment: @leoMestizo—edit with say 10 spurious characters, then edit again to remove them.